# D3.js set axis domain from bound data?

Tags: d3.js

In learning d3.js, I've seen [several](http://examples.oreilly.com/0636920026938/chapter_09/20_axes_dynamic.html) [examples](http://goo.gl/IJZTOA) of [d3 plots](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/) where the axes update when the data is changed.

I would have expected the axes to depend on bound data, so that when you add new data with .data(newData), the domain of the scale used by the axis would change. Instead, all of these examples join the data to the plot selection and then manually redraw the axes based on a different variable (often the original, unbound data variable).

Why aren't scales defined as a function of bound data? Perhaps this is leads to a circular reference problem? Or does it go against d3 philosophy for some other reason?

Comment: Scales and the data bound to DOM elements are completely independent entities. The scales are used to determine how to display elements from the data bound to them. Adding a direct link as you've outlined would for example prevent you from using more than one representation/scale per data element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up tying the axes to the data myself, and it seems to work well. I have an updatePlot function that adds new data to the plot, a getDataExtents that returns the extents of the data, and a setAxesBounds function which sets the domain of the scales and then does .call to redraw the axes. Inside updatePlot, I just have setAxesBounds(getDataExtents(data)) so that whenever data is updated, the axes are redrawn with scales based on the data.

I'm used to plotting libraries where this sort of thing happens for you automatically, but I understand the d3 is not a plotting library and so it makes sense that it doesn't do this sort of thing for you, in the name of flexibility and to avoid unpredictable default behavior.